# I keep getting "SQL command not properly ended", Any help would be apprecieted

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried and I cant figure out why I keep getting an error.
I have looked over the commas, parenthesis and semicolons and don't see any issues.

```sql
SELECT INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE.BUSINESS_NAME, INVOICE_ITEM.PRODUCT_SKU AS PRODUCT_SKU, INVOICE_ITEM.QUANTITY_ORDERED AS QUANTITY
FROM INVOICE_ITEM
INNER JOIN INVOICE ON INVOICE_ITEM.INVOICE_NUMBER = INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER
GROUP BY BUSINESS
ORDER BY QUANTITY_ORDERED DESC
WHERE QUANTITY_ORDERED > (
SELECT DISTINCT BUSINESS_NAME AS BUSINESS, PRODUCT_SKU, SUM(QUANTITY_ORDERED)
FROM INVOICE_ITEM group by BUSINESS_NAME, PRODUCT_SKU
WHERE PRODUCT_SKU = 'UJT123' AND QUANTITY >= 3
);
```

I'm trying to get an output of invoice number - business name - and quantity ordered more than 3 (can be across multiple orders).

Comment: The `WHERE` clause comes before the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: What does it mean that `QUANTITY_ORDERED` is greater than a whole result set table?

Comment: It is my understanding that attributeName > )  is the way to start a nested SELECT statement

Comment: @Slater: You *can* use  `QUANTITY_ORDERED > (...)`, but only if that subquery returns one single value. Look at it like this: You can write `QUANTITY_ORDERED > 123`, but you cannot write `QUANTITY_ORDERED > 123 , 250, 400` or even `QUANTITY_ORDERED > apples 123 , bananas 250, peaches 400`. So after the `>` there must come a single number or a subquery returning a single number. Your subquery does not only return more than one column, but also more than one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is because the `WHERE` clause goes before the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY` clauses.

Your second issue is because you are not either including the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregating the columns.

What you appear to want to do is to use a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(i.INVOICE_NUMBER, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY invoice_number)
         AS invoices,
       i.BUSINESS_NAME,
       ii.PRODUCT_SKU,
       SUM(ii.QUANTITY_ORDERED) AS QUANTITY
FROM   INVOICE_ITEM ii
       INNER JOIN INVOICE i
       ON ii.INVOICE_NUMBER = i.INVOICE_NUMBER
WHERE  PRODUCT_SKU = 'UJT123'
GROUP BY
       i.business_name,
       ii.product_sku
HAVING SUM(ii.quantity_ordered) > 3
ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

However, without having an example of your sample data and the expected output it is difficult to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

- `where` clause is on wrong place
- you're trying to compare quantity to 3 columns subquery returns, and that won't work - perhaps you'll have to correlate subquery to table(s) in the `from` clause
- `group by business` is most probably wrong; you'll have to put all columns you select in there, or not use `group by` (substitute it with `distinct`)

Something like this:

```
  SELECT invoice.invoice_number,
         invoice.business_name,
         invoice_item.product_sku AS product_sku,
         invoice_item.quantity_ordered AS quantity
    FROM invoice_item ii
         INNER JOIN invoice
            ON invoice_item.invoice_number = invoice.invoice_number
   WHERE quantity_ordered > (  SELECT SUM (quantity_ordered)
                                 FROM invoice_item ii1
                                WHERE     ii1.business_name = ii.business_name
                                      AND ii1.product_skup = ii.product_sku
                                      AND product_sku = 'UJT123'
                                      AND quantity >= 3
                             GROUP BY business_name, product_sku)
ORDER BY quantity_ordered DESC;
```